# Using "KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1" did not resolve "no matching key exchange method found" error

Tags: windows, git, ssh

There's a lot of questions about the following error, but they all have same solution which did not have any effect:

```
$ git push
Unable to negotiate with 192.168.XXX.XXX: no matching key exchange method found. Their offer: diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

There is an [article on openssh.com](http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html) that didn't help. Particularly this was suggested:

> ... in the ~/.ssh/config file:
>
> ```
> Host somehost.example.org
> KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
> ```

I did exactly that. I assume that `~` resolves to `%userprofile%` on windows. My file is in `C:\Users\MY_USERNAME\.ssh\config`:

```
## use kex algorithm ##
Host 192.168.XXX.XXX
KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

The result is that nothing changed. There is also suggestion to use `ssh -o` but I'm yet to find an answer that bothers to describe how exactly yo do that. I tried this:

```
$ ssh -oKexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
```

I need to connect to that GIT repository. I am on windows. The repository uses Gerrit. I also use SourceTree and it **has no problems pushing into the repository**. So the repository works, but git or openSSH in my bash is broken.

What did I do wrong that this solution didn't work for me?

Comment: Try running ssh with the "-vv" flag. It'll print the names of the config files which it reads, and it'll print details of the key exchange.

Comment: You say you did the same thing in the config file, but your config file doesn't show that you did.  You had `KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group1-sha1` but needed  `KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1`.  Notice the `+` before diffie.

Comment: @BrianPursley Hah, 5 years later I finally know what I did wrong and why the command in my answer worked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Resolved by using this command I randomly found in some comment thread:

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND='ssh -o KexAlgorithms=+diffie-hellman-group1-sha1'
```

Must be called every time you open the Git Bash. Yeah, git is hell.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved a similar problem on Windows 10 by updating my version of Open SSH to the latest (7.5p1-1) and then making sure that C:Program Files\OpenSSH\bin was the first entry in the system path so it used that ssh.exe and not any others.

Answer (score 0):

I started getting this error after updating to "git for windows" to version 2.25.1
[This algo was deprecated by GitHub in Feb. of 2018.](https://github.blog/2017-09-18-crypto-deprecation-notice-update-1/)

@Kenster's comment on "use ssh -vv ..." to see where your config files live was key. 
My home drive in windows is a network drive so my default .ssh folder is on that network volume.

Adding a file called "config" to that folder with:

```
Host 127.0.0.1
Port 2222
KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
```

allowed me to connect to my vagrant environment again.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue.Please install the older version of "Git for Windows".
https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases/tag/v2.17.1.windows.1
This version will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue using Git for Windows 2.27.0.

Git for Windows brings its own OpenSSH implementation. I had to change the config file C:\Program Files\Git\etc\ssh_config

```
Host myhost@example.com
    Port 22
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
    KexAlgorithms +diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
```